# Mkdocs with README as index containing images with broken links

Tags: python, mkdocs

I've been trying to build a doc site with [Mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) with `doc_dir=docs/`. Let's say I would like to use my `README.md` contents for the homepage.
The contents of this file are copied into `docs/index.md`.

This README happens to contain links to images, which reside in the `docs/img` folder.
The documentation is successfully built, and the README is indeed shown as the homepage. However, the images are not showing.

This is the structure of the project:

```
README.md     # <- contains link to docs/img/img1.png
docs/
    index.md  # <- same contents as README.md
    img/
        img1.png
```

The problem is that `index.md` contains faulty links to the images, since relative to this file, the images are actually under `img/`. When I try to copy the correct folder structure for the images in the `site` directory (containing the built website), the images still do not show.

I could maybe symlink the `README.md` and the linked images inside the `docs/` folder, but isn't there a cleaner way to do that?

Comment: You should first make sure that you really see the README.md and not the index.md by using a dummy entry. [Edit] your question and add the essential parts of your `mkdocs.yml`.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using `--8<-- "README.md"` in my `index.md`, and image links working in the readme are broken in the index.